# mysql, select with no duplicates with count, based on maximum value of different column

Tags: mysql, select, count, duplicates, max

I have fallowing table structure

```
|id|product_id|date|buyer_id|seler_id|
```

as a result of a query i need to have
not duplicated, product_id with maximum date and corresponding to it buyer_id and also quantity of buyers for this product_id

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*
from your_table t
inner join
(
   select product_id, max(date) as mdate
   from your_table
   group by product_id 
) x on x.product_id = t.product_id and x.mdate = t.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery gets the latest date for every `product_id`. To get the other columns, you need to join the subquery on the table itself on two conditions, that it matches the `product_id` and the `date`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product_id, MAX(date) date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY product_id
        ) b ON a.product_id = b.product_id AND
                a.date = b.date
```

This can also be done using correlated subquery,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.date = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(date) date
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.product_id = b.product_id
        )
```

- [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but i already figure it out how to get distinct product_id with last buyer, the problem is that i also need to know how many buyers bought this product